# PHP sqlsrv_query : Error while inserting data

Tags: php, sql, sql-insert, sqlsrv

I am trying to insert data into my database table in SQL Server. I am able to connect to the database and while inserting I get the following error:

`Errors: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42S02 [SQLSTATE] => 42S02 [1] => 208 [code] => 208 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'dbo.Salesforce'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'dbo.Salesforce'. ) )`

To keep things simple, I have hardcoded the values (instead of picking on form submit) that need to be inserted into the table:

```
/*Insert data.*/
$insertSql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Salesforce (ID,Name, Company, Email, Phone, Assets, Comm, Capability)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
/* Construct the parameter array. */
$ID = 5;
$Name = "Sarah";
$Company = "Track24";
$Email = "xxx@live.com";
$Phone = "+xxxxxx";
$Assets = "Vehicles";
$Comm = "GSM";
$Capability = "IVMS";
$params1 = array($ID,
               $Name,
               $Company,
               $Email,
               $Phone,
               $Assets,
               $Comm,
               $Capability);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $insertSql, $params1);
if($stmt === false)
{
die('Errors: ' . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), TRUE));
}
else
{
echo '<br clear="all"><label style="color:red;">Thank you for your details.</label>';
}
```

The fields that are called above are not all the fields of the table. There are a few more but since they allow `null` values, I did not include them. I have googled for this error but unable to understand what it actually means and where is the issue! Any pointers?

EDIT 1: Successfully connects through:

```
/* Specify the server and connection string attributes. */
$serverName = "xxxx-PC\SQLExpress";
$connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"Salesforce");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
if($conn === false)
{
      die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: is the connection running? "dbo" exists? and "Salesforce"?

Comment: @Igoel yes the connection is running. I am able to connect successfully. I added the connection string above in my edit. Is the error related to connecting to the db?

Comment: He can´t find the table I think, so Salesforce exists or isn`t mistyped?

Comment: Thanks @Igoel, that was the issue. Solved it. +1 for pointing to the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I think your Query as wrong. Please check the query with right syntax.

*$insertSql = "INSERT INTO tablename (ID,Name, Company, Email, Phone, Assets, Comm, Capability)
VALUES (val1,val2,val3,val4.....)";*

Comment: If you think the "?" are wrong....this is a prepared statement, so it´s fine what he did